# How to validate a trivia question with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

let me preface by saying I am relatively new to coding.
So as part of a project, I am trying to create a trivia game using Flask/HTML/CSS/Javascript and the open trivia DB API.
So far I have managed to send a request to the API and get back the list of questions based on user input.
Then I pass these questions to my trivia template and pick them up with JavaScript to show them on the screen.

Below my JavaScript and HTML to show the questions on the screen and my attempt to validate the question. I get all sorts of weird results, from clicking once on the button and showing 3-4 alerts, to clicking on the correct answer and the alarm showing wrong. I am assuming I need to do this with async/await/promises but That is kind of beyond my level. Any ideas where this is going wrong?

```js
debugger;
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
}

function isAnswerCorrect(correctAnswer) {
    let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("answers");
    for (let i=0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            if(buttons[i].innerHTML === correctAnswer) {
                console.log(correctAnswer);
                alert("Correct!");
                return;
            }
            else {
                console.log(correctAnswer);
                alert("Wrong!");
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}

const parseQuestions = async () => {
    for (let question in questions) {
        document.querySelector("#category").innerHTML = questions[question]['category'];
        document.querySelector("#difficulty").innerHTML = questions[question]['difficulty'];
        document.querySelector("#question").innerHTML = questions[question]['question'];
        let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("answers");
        // console.log(questions[question]['answers']);
        shuffleArray(questions[question]['answers']);
        // console.log(questions[question]['answers']);
        if (questions[question]['answers'].length > 2){
            for (let i=0; i < buttons.length; i++){
                buttons[i].style.removeProperty('display');
                buttons[i].innerHTML = questions[question]['answers'][i];
            }
        } else {
            for (let i=0; i < buttons.length; i++){
                if (typeof(questions[question]['answers'][i]) === 'undefined') {
                    buttons[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                else{
                    buttons[i].innerHTML = questions[question]['answers'][i];
                }
            }
        }
        isAnswerCorrect(questions[question]['correct_answer']);
        await delay(5000);
    }
}

parseQuestions();
```

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Questions
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
        <h3 id="category"></h3>
        <div id="difficulty"></div>
        <div id="question"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary answers" id="answer1"></button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary answers" id="answer2"></button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary answers" id="answer3"></button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary answers" id="answer4"></button>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
var questions = {{ questions|tojson }};
{% endblock %}
```

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width">

    <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" rel="stylesheet">
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"></script>

    <link href="/static/question.ico" rel="icon">
    <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/static/get_questions.js" defer></script>

    <title>Trivia: 
Questions
```

```
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="bg-dark border navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Playground</a>
            <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-target="#navbar" data-bs-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mt-2">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/trivia">Trivia</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/stats">Stats</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mt-2">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    

    <main class="container-fluid py-5 text-center">
        
    <h3 id="category"></h3>
    <div id="difficulty"></div>
    <div id="question"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary answers" id="answer1"></button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary answers" id="answer2"></button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary answers" id="answer3"></button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary answers" id="answer4"></button>

    </main>

</body>


  <script defer>
        
var questions = [{"answers": ["Patella", "Tibia", "Fibula ", "Radius"], "category": "Science \u0026 Nature", "correct_answer": "Radius", "difficulty": "easy", "incorrect_answers": ["Patella", "Tibia", "Fibula ", "Radius"], "question": "Which of the following bones is not in the leg?", "type": "multiple"}, {"answers": ["Carson", "Jackson", "Willy", "Wilson"], "category": "Entertainment: Film", "correct_answer": "Wilson", "difficulty": "easy", "incorrect_answers": ["Carson", "Jackson", "Willy", "Wilson"], "question": "In the movie \u0026quot;Cast Away\u0026quot; the main protagonist\u0026#039;s best friend while on the island is named", "type": "multiple"}, {"answers": ["53", "443", "23", "80"], "category": "Science: Computers", "correct_answer": "80", "difficulty": "hard", "incorrect_answers": ["53", "443", "23", "80"], "question": "What port does HTTP run on?", "type": "multiple"}, {"answers": ["Matt Burnett", "Ian Jones Quartey", "Ben Leven", "Rebecca Sugar"], "category": "Entertainment: Music", "correct_answer": "Rebecca Sugar", "difficulty": "hard", "incorrect_answers": ["Matt Burnett", "Ian Jones Quartey", "Ben Leven", "Rebecca Sugar"], "question": "Who designed the album cover for True Romance, an album by Estelle?", "type": "multiple"}, {"answers": ["Hopper", "Silver Stripe", "Woebegone", "Gooty"], "category": "Animals", "correct_answer": "Gooty", "difficulty": "hard", "incorrect_answers": ["Hopper", "Silver Stripe", "Woebegone", "Gooty"], "question": "Which of the following is another name for the \u0026quot;Poecilotheria Metallica Tarantula\u0026quot;?", "type": "multiple"}];

    </script>
```

Comment: `"my attempt to validate the question"` - why do you need to validate the question? `"I get all sorts of weird results, from clicking once on the button and showing 3-4 alerts, to clicking on the correct answer and the alarm showing wrong"` can you share these errors - a screenshot perhaps of the console?

Comment: By validate I mean check if the answer is correct. The idea is to store how many answers the user has correct, how many wrong then send it to the backend to store in a database.  For example in the question on the screenshot I have clicked on the correct answer and I get an alert that it's wrong https://imgur.com/3ILVPwQ

Comment: And the errors.... can you add a screenshot of them or copy and edit the question? Can you add some of the rendered HTML (view page source) so that the above code can be made into a working (with errors) example?

Comment: That screenshotr suggests `no errors` and there is a mainly obscured `dialog` stating `Wrong!`

Comment: It is not errors that I am getting, more unexpected behaviour. I have added HTML of my rendered template as well. Basically whenever I click on a button the alert will scroll through all previous answers first until it reaches the answer currently on screen. Maybe this picture clears it up a bit: https://imgur.com/WkuAIvT

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional information. You mention Flask in the question, are you fetching data from the [Open Trivia API](https://opentdb.com/) with Flask/Python and storing the resultant JSON or is this all done within the browser?

Comment: Yeah I get the response from Open trivia API indeed and pass it to my render_template, then I wanted to handle everything else with javascript and just send the results back to my back end once all the questions have been answered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248545/discussion-between-professor-abronsius-and-kronivar).

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned in chat ( did you see? ) about a working demo in PHP but felt that as you were trying to do this entirely in Javascript ( except using Flask/Python for backend stuff ) that I'd modify things to run entirely in js.

I knocked up your code as a working snippet and indeed it does not perform correctly so ended up experimenting until I reached the following.
I could not see the benefit of what you were trying to do with `async` and `await` - as there was no need to make further asynchronous ajax requests once the initial data was determined there became no need for that approach. You might need that if each question was fetched from your server, the answer then sent back to your server and the result sent back to you but otherwise not needed.

I hope it helps but one thing to note - by doing this all in js ( as also in your original code ) it does become easy to cheat if one so wishes! You should be able to run this as a snippet

```js
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
  let i = this.length;
  while (i > 0) {
  let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
  i--;
  let t = this[i];
  this[i] = this[n];
  this[n] = t;
  }
  return this;
};

// Begin process by fetching some random questions from opentrivia
fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5')
  .then(r=>r.json())
  .then(json=>{
    // send the results to the next part of the chain
    return json.results;
  })
  .then( questions=>{
    // declare various variables 
    let index=0;
    let score=0;
    let statistics={};

    const d=document;
    // find references to DOM elements
    const bttns=[...d.querySelectorAll('button.answers')];
    const cat=d.getElementById('category');
    const dif=d.getElementById('difficulty');
    const que=d.getElementById('question');
    const tot=d.getElementById('total');
    const ver=d.getElementById('verdict');

    // reset button to basic state
    const resetbttn=( bttn,hide=true )=>{
      Object.keys( bttn.dataset ).forEach(key=>{
        bttn.removeAttribute( `data-{key}` );
      })
      bttn.innerHTML='';
      bttn.hidden=hide;
    };
    // reset all buttons to basic, hidden state
    const resetbuttons=()=>{
      bttns.forEach( bttn=>{
        resetbttn( bttn )
      });
    }

    // using the global index variable, find the question in the source array
    const askquestion = () => {
      let q = questions[index];
      // combine incorrect & correct answers into an array and shuffle it.
      let a = q.incorrect_answers.concat( q.correct_answer ).shuffle();
      // hide all the buttons
      resetbuttons();

      // show buttons for which there is an answer and assign properties
      a.forEach((v,i)=>{
        resetbttn( bttns[i],false );
        bttns[i].innerHTML=v;
        bttns[i].dataset.index=index;
        bttns[i].dataset.value=v;
      });
      // advance the counter index so that the next question can be identified.
      index++;

      // populate DOM elements
      que.innerHTML=q.question;
      que.dataset.index=index;
      cat.innerHTML=q.category;
      dif.innerHTML=q.difficulty;
      tot.dataset.total=questions.length;
    };


    // invoked by the delegated event handler
    const getanswer=(e)=>{
      if( index <= questions.length ) {
        // use dataset attributes to determine correct 
        // answer after doing a lookup into source array
        let a=e.target.dataset.value;
        let i=e.target.dataset.index;
        let q=questions[i];

        if( a === q.correct_answer ) {
          score++;
          tot.dataset.score=score;
          ver.innerHTML='Correct!';
        }else{
          ver.innerHTML=`Sorry, that is not correct. The correct answer is <span>"${q.correct_answer}"</span>`;
        }
        // update the statistics
        statistics[ index ]={
          correct:a === q.correct_answer,
          question:q.question,
          answer:q.correct_answer,
          player:a
        }

        if( index < questions.length ) askquestion();
        else endquiz();
      }
    };

    const endquiz=()=>{
      bttns.forEach( n=>n.disabled=true );
      console.log( statistics );// send statistics to backend??
      alert('game over');
    }



    // listen for clicks on any/all of the buttons
    d.addEventListener('click', e => {
      if( e.target.classList.contains('answers') && e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON' ) {
        getanswer(e);
      }
    });

  // start the quiz...
  askquestion();
})
```

```css
#category:before,
#difficulty:before,
#question:before,
#verdict:before,
#score:before {
  content: attr(id)': ';
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: green;
}

[data-score]:after {
  content: attr(data-score)'/'attr(data-total)
}

div,
span,
button {
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

button {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

div>span {
  color: red
}

#question:before {
  content: attr(id) ' ['attr(data-index)'] : ';
}
```

```html
<main class='container-fluid py-5 text-center'>
  <h3 id='category'></h3>
  <div id='difficulty'></div>
  <div id='question' data-index=1></div>
  <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary answers'></button>
  <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary answers'></button>
  <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary answers'></button>
  <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary answers'></button>
  <div id='verdict'></div>
  <span id='total' data-score=0 data-total></span>
</main>
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for this! I did see your message yesterday and replied. I'll play around with this code to understand what exactly it is doing before attempting to do something similar my self.  
How is using pure javascript more prone to cheating?

Comment: RE: the cheating aspect. Anything within the browser is observable by the user ( view source, inspect using console etc. ) As you have downloaded, to the browser, the Q&A data it is trivial to find that original source data and from that ...cheat! With the code I did here the ajax request is visible to the user if they use the console tools. The only way to keep this secure, that I can think of just now, would be to maintain the Q&A on the server and send only question and answers back and forth...only the server would know the truth within the data.

Answer (score 0):

By looping through all the questions and calling `isAnswerCorrect()` every time, every 5 seconds, you add more and more event listeners to the buttons. You can remove old event listeners (learn more here: https://www.coderepublics.com/JavaScript/JavaScript-event-listener.php) but I would recommend implementing another logic:

1. Load all questions
2. Initialize a variable to keep track of the current position in the question array
3. Get question[index] and draw it to the screen
4. Remove all eventListeners from the answer buttons
5. Add new eventlisteners like `()=>{handleAnswer(true)}` for right answers
6. In handleAnswer() you need to increase the score, show your alert, end the game if there are no more questions, and lastly call the function showNextQuestion(), starting with the steps at 3

I hope this helps!